# Can I use a scalar function as the table name in .create table control command?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a stored function that generates an identity name based on a set of parameters like this:

```
.create function 
with (docstring = 'Returns the table name for the specified data log provider.')
GetTableName(param1: string, param2: string)
{
    // Some string cleansing and concatenation
    let tableName = strcat(system, source);
    tableName
}
```

I want to use this function to create a table. Tried the following options with no success:

```
.create table GetTableName('value1', 'value2') (Timestamp: datetime)
.create table [GetTableName('value1', 'value2')] (Timestamp: datetime)
```

I'm guessing the command expects the table name to be a string literal. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control commands that create tables cannot include query execution (and vise versa: queries cannot run control commands).
The restriction exists for security reasons.

You can achieve the scenario using client code and having two calls:
1) Derive table name 
2) Generate table create command and send it to the server.